# how to integration Facebook into jomsocial(joomla component)?

Tags: facebook, joomla

how to integration Facebook into jomsocial(joomla component)?
my site link is
http://speedfive.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got through it.

Create Application at www.facebook.com/developer

Use App Id and key, at your backend => Jomsocial => Facebook Connect

Reade these

http://www.jomsocial.com/support/docs.html

http://www.jomsocial.com/support/docs/item/763-common-fbc-issues.html

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days fudging around with jomsocial's stupid facebook connect module. Page errors... javascript conflicts... blank popup windows...

I finally gave up on their half-baked connector and went with a 3rd party component called JFBConnect from sourcecoast (here: http://www.sourcecoast.com/extensions/jfbconnect?amigosid=131).

I had that up and running in 10 minutes and it perfectly integrates facebook into my site. It also includes a bunch of extras such as ability to add the "sign in with facebook" button wherever, page 'like' plugin, activity stream, fan box, etc.